# NodeJS/Mysql - Convert RowDataPacket Result to String

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, backend

I have this statement:

```
File.getAvatars = async (req, result) => {
    try {
        const users = await db.query(
            `SELECT id FROM users WHERE familyid = 2`,
            [req]
        );

        const avatars = await db.query(
            `SELECT fileName FROM users WHERE userId = ?`,
            [users]
        );

        if (!users) {
            console.log('File not found');
            return result(null, new Error('File not found'));
        }

        const metadata = await bucket.file(fileName).getMetadata();

        return result(null, metadata);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('Error selecting from AVATARS: ', err);
        return result(null, err);
    }
};
```

I want the first statement results ("const users...") to be used to look up rows in another table (the next query, "const avatars...") - but this fails because the result of query 1 comes in as RowDataPackets:

```
0 = RowDataPacket {id: 1}
1 = RowDataPacket {id: 3}
```

...which cannot be used in the next query. I need to process the values of const users so that only the values are passed into the next query and as a comma-separated string ("1, 3..."). How can I do this? I have tried a number of solutions but nothing quite gets me there.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I needed this after the first query:

```
const userList = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(users));
const userArray = userList.flat();

let ids = [];
userList.forEach( (element) => {
            ids.push(element.id);
        });
console.log(ids);
```